# Using Ada on macOS

Tags: software-recommendation, big-sur, macos

I have a need to do a couple of small personal projects on macOS.  I am considering updating my Ada knowledge (it has changed a bit) instead of learning Swift from the very beginning.

My projects do not require an IDE or GUI: text/command-line is adequate.  But I do have Xcode installed (never used).  **If I use Ada (from GNAT/AdaCore), will it integrate with Xcode, or can I make it independent and just use command-line?**

Questions and answers from earlier versions of macOS make me think the methods they suggest may have problems with Big Sur 11.6 (20G165).  Anything I need to know beyond the Linux/Windows instructions in the GNAT Readme file?

I also have a MBP with Mojave, which I can use if GNAT has trouble with Big Sur.  But I'd prefer the newer one.

Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091088/cant-make-ada-work-with-xcode-3-2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100240/how-to-install-ada-ide-and-compiler-on-mac-osx

Comment: Worst case, I could pull an old box out of the closet and put Linux on it.

Comment: Is this a question about how to integrate Ada into Xcode 12/13, about how to install GNAT on macOS or about the best way to develop in Ada on macOS?

Comment: It's not exactly any of those.  Mainly, not how to integrate it but does it/must it integrate?  In thirty years of software engineering, the only times I tried an IDE, I found it more productive to return to simple CLI and text.

Comment: @WGroleau No need for worse case - Use Docker or VirtualBox or other VMs to run Linux.  Also is your machine Intel or Apple Silicon

Comment: Even using swift or objective C on macOS you can do it all from the command line you don't need to run Xcode - Xcode is just the GUI all the programming languages it supports actually compile through the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no requirement to use Xcode as such. If you're using the GNAT Community build, you'll need to have it installed though (free download).

You can just use the GNAT compiler directly as you would on other systems. There's no need to actually open Xcode and use the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

XCode hasn't supported Ada in many years, but still has some vestiges which can lead to some confusion. Nowadays, your best bet is to use the following development stack for modern Ada development, which works across MacOS, Windows and Linux:

1. **Alire**, a package, toolchain and project management utility for Ada.
2. **VSCode**, Microsoft's IDE
3. **Ada Extension for VSCode**, provides Ada language support for VSCode with syntax coloring, snippets, Intellisense, Autoformatting, etc.

There's probably other commercial solutions available, including GNATStudio, but Alire has changed the game, giving Ada the same modern and productive developer experience found in other languages.

Comment: "Alire requires a recent Ada 2012 compiler"—in other words, it is NOT a replacement for GNAT and will not help me compile "a couple of small personal projects."

VSCode with Ada extensions also is not a compiler, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847136/ada-extension-for-visual-studio-2019 suggests using GNAT with it might not be fun.

I used Visual Studio a lot before I retired.  Even if it worked smoothly with a compiler, it seems like overkill and a waste of disk space for "a couple of small personal projects."

Comment: It's been a long time, but I wrote over fifty thousand lines of Ada, and an unknown amount of SQL, Pascal, Java, and others without an IDE.  Visual Studio was the only IDE I ever tried that wasn't a hindrance.  Anyway, no matter hw good an IDE might be, recommending it does not answer the question I asked.

Comment: You sound like you've been out of the Ada and software development loop for a while. It would behoove you to ask for clarifications, or at the very least, do some cursory research rather than assume I didn’t address your question. First, Alire isn’t trying to replace GNAT. It is a helper utility for installing and configuring  a complete GNAT compiler and toolchain install. It is also a package manager for managing  dependencies and libraries. You never specified what version of Ada you require, which makes little sense since GNAT 2012 is fully backwards compatible.

Comment: Second, you said you don't require an IDE, not that you DIDN'T WANT an IDE. Any developer experienced with GNAT knows it support the command-line by default. Moreover, I suggested VSCode (Visual Studio Code) as an IDE because you asked about Xcode. Finally, I presumed you already arrived at a solution given the age of this question. My primary goal is to provide an alternative answer for others with the same question.

Comment: I know the command line is available and said so.  The question was about integration with XCode.